# After update from Debian Stretch to Buster I cannot open links from applications

Tags: debian, links

I recently updated from Debian Stretch to Buster. I first got aware I cannot open links from inside Rambox. I addressed an issue on GitHub but now I found out I cannot open links from inside PHPStorm and any other application either.

I always get the following error message in a dialog box

```
-------------------- Error --------------------

 (-) /home/johndoe/https:/example.com/path/to/
     resource.php: No such file or directory

                                        [ Ok ]
```

As one can see there's always the path to my home directory placed in front of the link.

I won't reinstall my system as a whole.

---

**Edit (2019-08-18):**

While it's an issue of the Desktop Environment I forgot to mention I'm using `LXDE`.

---

**Edit (2019-08-19):**

I found `xdg-open` which leads to the same error.

```
xdg-open https://example.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's sure that `xdg-open` is broken. This has been addressed at

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=908760#20